# Creating a table based on a mysql view result for faster fetch

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

So our website has growing data and we usually use mysql views for lists of records so that we can simplify the select query in our codes. That has been the practice since, but over time, the requirements introduced a lot of complexities to the SQL views, like sum, count of, etc. So most of our views are relatively slower.

To retain the logic created in MySQL views (since that is our client preference is), we did tried the following:

Option 1 is to:

1. Spun up RDS 2
2. Select * from view from our RDS 1
3. Insert into all the result in RDS 2
4. Connect the Lists APIs to fetch data from RDS 2

With #4 it returns fast because the database will not re evaluate the sum, count anymore we just have to fetch the result.
#2 & #3:

- Our API server is running nodejs, and it connects to those 2 databases.
- I only save 1000 per list/table. So if I have 6 views = 6 flat tables being created.
- Happens at least every minute. We implemented a flag to check if there is on going process before repeating the whole process.

Problem with this option: it strains our RDS 1 and API server.

Option 2 is to:

1. Create another table on the same RDS 1
2. Insert into select from sql view
3. Connect the list API to fetch data from the created flat table

Problem with this option: Haven’t tested it in our test environments but in my local when #2 is on going, updating some of table rows is not possible and I am getting deadlock errors.

Not sure if I am on the right track or if this even has a solution besides recoding or fixing our database structure or opting out totally from using MySQL views.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems that you need some kind of a cache, rather than a 2nd database or table.

Comment: Yeah, like redis. Then I just need to spin up another replica reader so I can redirect all select query to that and not affect the other transactions...

Answer (score 1):

"sum, count of, etc" -- This smacks of a "report" against a large "Fact" table in a Data Warehouse.

**Plan A -- Summary Tables**

If the data is static (after it is inserted), then build and maintain Summary Tables.  This will be much faster and more efficient all around.  You can still put a `VIEW` or `Stored Proc` in front of the necessary `SELECTs.

Such Summary tables would live on the same instance and might take only 20% extra disk space.  And, because they run so much faster, there is no need to set up another server.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

`VIEWs` are syntactic sugar.  They are never(?) faster than the underlying `SELECT`, and sometimes slower.  They do, as your customer says, make querying easier.

**Plan B -- Replication**

A different approach for handling too many queries (as opposed to handling slow queries) is to use "replication".  Writes go to the Primary and get replicated to the Replicas.  Your `VIEWs` can hit the Replicas since they are (I assume) readonly.  Any number of Replicas can be added, leading to 'infinite' scaling.

(Both A and B can be done.)

Comment: Plan A - yep, that has been proposed but that would mean, we are going to update the summary tables in most pages that affects the summary table.

Plan B - our RDS is in aurora currently have writer and a reader replica. Client willing to spend to upgrade but not futuristic because it is not cost effective.

Comment: @JanLmpn - Elaborate on how you envision summary tables.  I have implemented them several times -- with very little overhead.